# How to validate representativeness of survey on new social group?

Tags: survey-sampling, representative

Say a new social group X emerges in society. Say you take a sample from individuals in this group X. How to validate the sample's representativeness?

For samples of other parts of society, you have a census to compare with. The census will tell you if the sample is representative or not. If not,  you can adjust with known weights.

But in this case, the new group emerged post-census. One solution is to have a mini-census of the new group, which is quite difficult and expensive. Is there an alternative?

Comment: How do you identify individuals of this group?  How do you choose them for sampling?  Both these things are critical for understanding and answering your question.

Comment: @whuber That is precisely part of the problem. One could try different sampling strategies. The point is to evaluate which is better or more representative.

Comment: I still can't tell what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try my best to interpret your question in a way I understand.

Once you have declared a population, the next thing you do is declare a sampling frame. A sampling frame is a source from which you draw a sample. Your sampling frame may or may not contain the entirety of the population, so you are going to be concerned with whether the sampling frame has good coverage or whether the coverage it is lacking is missing completely at random  (in which case you are still solid).

Assumptions made about a sampling frame are fundamentally extra-data assumptions. If you are able to validate a sampling frame with data, then you would have to compare it with a different collection of data which has your initial sampling frame as a subset. If this is the case, then you would be insane to not switch to using that larger list as your sampling frame instead.

Operationalizing group membership is going to be more conceptual rather than statistical; therefore, questions concerning "how should I define group membership" is going to be thrown up to domain expertise regarding that group and the philosophical chops of the practitioner. Some group memberships are fundamentally one of self-identification (like "gender" or "gamer") and are therefore going to require some kind of survey since I can't look at someone and go "ah yes, you're 6'4" and wear a football jersey... definitely not a gamer". If your population is every member of that subgroup in an entire country, then guess what? You're doing a census and there is no way around it. Your only option is to lower your inferential goals by either redefining your population or your research question.

Answer (score 0):

Without correct labeling for a large enough sample, it is unrealistic to expect to solve this problem. Although mini-census is expensive, if you want accurate results, I don't see any other way besides waiting for group X to grow large enough to reach the minimum subsample size available at the earliest time point in different groups.